# Get element id from loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have loop and i need to get data-id when fa-star class inside i tag is clicked, but when i try to do this i always get id only from the first row, not from what i clicked.

```
<div data-id="1" class="companies-list-item-rating">
    <i data-rate="1" class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
    <i data-rate="2" class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
    <i data-rate="3" class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
    <i data-rate="4" class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
    <i data-rate="5" class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
    <span class="companies-list-item-rating-count">/ 7</span>
</div><!-- /.companies-list-item-rating -->

<div data-id="2" class="companies-list-item-rating">
    <i data-rate="1" class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
    <i data-rate="2" class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
    <i data-rate="3" class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
    <i data-rate="4" class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
    <i data-rate="5" class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
    <span class="companies-list-item-rating-count">/ 3</span>
</div><!-- /.companies-list-item-rating -->
```

```js
$('.fa-star-o').click(function() {
    var object_id = $('.companies-list-item-rating').data('id');
    alert(object_id);
});
```

Comment: You can simple get using `var object_id = $(this).parent().data('id');`

Comment: I like this, simple and clean

Answer (score 2):

Use `this` to refer the clicked element inside the handler then get the div using **[`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)** or **[`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)** method.

```js
$('.fa-star-o').click(function() {
  var object_id = $(this).closest('.companies-list-item-rating').data('id');
  // or var object_id = $(this).parent().data('id');
  alert(object_id);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-id="1" class="companies-list-item-rating">
  <i data-rate="1" class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
  <i data-rate="2" class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
  <i data-rate="3" class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
  <i data-rate="4" class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
  <i data-rate="5" class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
  <span class="companies-list-item-rating-count">/ 7</span>
</div>
<!-- /.companies-list-item-rating -->

<div data-id="2" class="companies-list-item-rating">
  <i data-rate="1" class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
  <i data-rate="2" class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
  <i data-rate="3" class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
  <i data-rate="4" class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
  <i data-rate="5" class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
  <span class="companies-list-item-rating-count">/ 3</span>
</div>
<!-- /.companies-list-item-rating -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the nearest `companies-list-item-rating` element relative to where you clicked by using `$(this)` via the [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) function :

```
$('.fa-star-o').click(function() {
   // This will find the nearest matching element
   var object_id = $(this).closest('.companies-list-item-rating').data('id');
   alert(object_id);
});
```

Your previous approach would have simply attempting to find the first element with the `companies-list-item-rating` class and used it's `data-id` attribute each time. Using `$(this).closest(...)` will traverse up the DOM until it finds what you need contextually.

**Example**

[image]

```js
$('.fa-star-o').click(function() {
  var object_id = $(this).closest('.companies-list-item-rating').data('id');
  console.log(object_id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<div data-id="1" class="companies-list-item-rating">
  <i data-rate="1" class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
  <i data-rate="2" class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
  <i data-rate="3" class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
  <i data-rate="4" class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
  <i data-rate="5" class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
  <span class="companies-list-item-rating-count">/ 7</span>
</div>
<!-- /.companies-list-item-rating -->

<div data-id="2" class="companies-list-item-rating">
  <i data-rate="1" class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
  <i data-rate="2" class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
  <i data-rate="3" class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
  <i data-rate="4" class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
  <i data-rate="5" class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
  <span class="companies-list-item-rating-count">/ 3</span>
</div>
<!-- /.companies-list-item-rating -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **.attr()** to get any attribute, **closest()** will traversing up and get nearest element with such class

```
$('.fa-star-o').click(function() {
  var object_id = $(this).closest('.companies-list-item-rating').attr('data-id');
});
```